# asp.net calendar extender postback

Tags: asp.net, ajax, calendar, extender

Hello guys i been using asp.net calendars for giving the user filtering options over a grid table.
Now i decided to try the ajax extender to save some room on the page.
The moment the user clicks on one of the calendars the grid updates/changes  ( i got some code in the SelectionChanged of the calendars that after few rows gives 2 date values that are sent to the sql and used as the allowed date range for the filter/select command ).
Now my problem is that unlike the regular calendar the ajax extender got no postback and no selectionchanged event i can use code in , and i not so sure how to make it all work without those 2 options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calendar extender "extends" your control. You still use your control's events. The extender will basically "impersonate" a user typing text into the control...

Catch the events on the control that the extender is bound to, not the extender itself.

Comment: I actully tried that earlier but it didnt work, and after your answer i tried again and now i understand why it didnt work ,it seem to avoid post back if marked as read only , anyhow i made it false and adjusted accordingly so now it works thanks.